# LOTS of red pixels Meizu M2

Tags: graphics

I've had lots of red pixels with my Meizu M2 (Flyme 5.1.6.0G) when I increased luminosity
I tried JScreenFix with luminosity at 100% but I just got some more when luminosity is at 0%...
Anyone knows how to fix this ?
Thanks.

PS: It does not appear in screenshots

Comment: If it does not appear in screenshots then it's the hardware. Get your screen replaced.

Comment: Oh, isn't  there any other way to fix it ?

Comment: Let's wait for others to post a solution if any - that's why I posted mine as a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just had to make the color temperature a bit colder... and I see no red pixels, and rarely some blue ones !

Comment: Why downvoting ? It's the right answer